# Conditional Summing Across data.frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working on migrating analysis I do in Excel into R as my dataset is hitting the limits of Excel.

In Excel, I have a worksheet ("state") that performs a sumifs function, summing values from another worksheet ("member) that have the same state/week combination in "state".

I would like to do this in R, where "state" and "member" are data.frames. So, for all rows in the "state" data.frame, I would like to sum all the rows from the "member" data.frame that have the same state/week combination in "state".

Dataset

```
state=data.frame(state=c('MD','MD','MD','NY','NY','NY'), week = 1:3) 
member=data.frame(memID = 1:5, state = c('MD','MD','NY','NY','MD'),
              week = 1:3,
              value = c(24,43,34,54,33,35,33,11,42,23,14,12,42,4,23))
```

Desired Output

```
state = data.frame(state=c('MD','MD','MD','NY','NY','NY'), week = 1:3, 
              total = c(80,90,70,96,15,76))
```

Thank you!

---

**Edit:**

I oversimplified my example a bit too much initially - the sumifs also take into account multiple inequalities. So in this example, with the same data, how would I do a total where I only take the sum if the value is between 20 and 40?

The new Desired Output would be

```
state = data.frame(state=c('MD','MD','MD','NY','NY','NY'), week = 1:3, 
              total = c(80,33,58,0,0,34)    )
              state
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 aggregate(value~state+week, member, sum)
```

Or

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 setDT(member)[, list(total=sum(value)), list(state, week)]
```

#### Update

If you need to get the `sum` for 'value' between 20 and 40.

```
setDT(member)[, sum(value[between(value,20,40)]) ,list(state, week)]
```

Comment: However, I may have oversimplified my problem in asking this question. What would be the correct approach if for this same problem, I wanted the same sum but for weeks on or before the row week?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I've edited the post. Mainly, my question is how to do the same thing you explained, but for multiple conditions including inequalities